# How to properly use Google App Script "not" query operator for searchFolders() function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to to search through a shared drive for KPI reports that do not contain "Archived" in the name. But Im getting "Invalid argument: q" error

I have tried using "not title contains 'Archived'" and "title not contains 'Archived'"

```
var clientFolder = DriveApp.searchFiles("title contains 'KPI Report' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and modifiedDate >= '" + dateModified + "' not title contains 'Archived'");
```

Comment: No idea, just a quick guess: try `and not title`

Comment: wow i can't believe I didn't think about that! It works thanks!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Simply had to put "and" before "not title"! Credit to @Chris G.!

`var clientFolder = DriveApp.searchFiles("title contains 'KPI Report' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and modifiedDate >= '" + dateModified + "' and not title contains 'Archived'");`